# Preventing the oracle connection being get lost

Tags: oracle

How to prevent the connection to the oracle server being gets lost if it is kept for some ideal time

Comment: I just added another one also

Comment: OK, but these are two very different and unrelated questions, so you should post them separately.  Also, in both cases, more details are required from you to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Alright, for the first I am working on an  online system where its needs to make sure that the connection should not be lost

Comment: What kind of system/software is your online application running in?  Many application servers support creating connection pools of database connections that the app server takes the responsibility for maintaining.

Comment: Its online transaction processing system

Comment: Sachin, this is an issue for the client of your database, but you have given no information about what technology your application is using to connect to the oracle server.  In comments you say you are not using JDBC.  So then, what *are* you using?  You need to provide more detail than this to get any useful answers.

Comment: @Zac, lets keep the technology aside and take this as the simple problem in client server architecture, please suggest how to make sure that the connection to your remote database will not last  if kept idle for some time, by ideal I mean no transactions are performed on DB.

Comment: May I know the reason for down voting :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way that I knew to save the database connection from being getting lost is to send a dummy query after the threshhold time, By Threash hold I mean the time after which the connection to the database is expected to become idle or get lost.

Some thing like

```
Ping_time_to_DB=60

if(Current_time - Last_Ping_time > Ping_time_to_DB)
{
     --send a dummy query like 
       select 1 from dual;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the newest JDBC spec 4.0 there is a `isValid()` method available for a connection that allows you to check if the connection is usable, if not then get a new (reconnect) connection and execute your SQL.

Comment: Your answer is appreciable but I am not using JDBC. I want to do it in C